# Probability of 14 points in seven independent dice rolls

Tags: probability

> Suppose we throw a fair die seven times independently. Let $S=\sum_{i=1}^7X_i$ be the sum of all seven outcomes $X_i$. What is $\mathbb{P}(S=14)$?

How do we approach this problem? Counting seems devious.

Comment: 14= 7(2) so the "average" die would have to  be 2.  Let u be the number of "1" s rolled.  What are the possible rolls larger than 2?. For example, if there were NO "1"s,u= 0, there must be exactly 7 "2"s.  If there were 1 "1", u= 1, there would have to be 5 "2"s and one "3".

Comment: But does that make the counting less devious? Edit: I will try following your hint using Badjohn's post!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $Y_i=X_i-1$ and count the number $n$ of integer solutions of
$$\sum_{i=1}^7Y_i=14-7=7,\quad \text{with $Y_i\in\{0,1,2,3,4,5\}$}.$$
By [Stars and bars method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_(combinatorics)#Theorem_two) and the [Inclusion–exclusion principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle), it follows that
$$n=\underbrace{\binom{7+6}{6}}_{\text{number of solutions with all $Y_i\geq 0$}} -\underbrace{ 7\cdot 7}_{\text{number of solutions with all $Y_i\geq 0$}\\\text{ and with at least one $Y_i\geq 6$}}.$$
Then 
$$\mathbb{P}(S=14)=\frac{n}{6^7}.$$

Comment: Thanks a lot! It took me some time, but now I understand. The stars and bars method seems very helpful for this kind of problems.

Comment: Yes, it is. In this case I used the second statement:https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_(combinatorics)#Theorem_two_2

Comment: Yeah I read that page already, helped me understand instead of just use this method :)

Answer (score 3):

For a simple solution.  Figure out how the sum can be 14, to make the list a manageable size, systematically list them with the restriction that the dice are in ascending sequence:

$$1 1 1 1 1 3 6$$
$$1 1 1 1 1 4 5$$
$$1 1 1 1 2 2 6$$
$$...$$
$$2 2 2 2 2 2 2$$

Now figure out how many ways each can be rearranged.  E.g. $7 \times 6 / 2$ for the first and just $1$ for the last.  So, now you know how many ways the sum can be achieved.  Divide by the total possibilities of $6^7$ and you have your answer.